# Perl Removing New Line

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I cant seem to remove the new line from an output I get by executing a command on linux server and have tried several different ways

heres my code **1st try**

```
$location = `curl -m 5 -sI 216.58.219.206 | grep "Location:"`;
chomp ($location);
print "before\n";
print "$location";
print "after\n";
```

output, Doesnt work, it gets printed with a new line.

```
before
Location: http://www.google.com/
after
```

**2nd try**

```
$location = `curl -m 5 -sI 216.58.219.206 | grep "Location:"`;
$location =~ s/\n//g;
print "before\n";
print "$location";
print "after\n";
```

Output, still doesn't work.

```
before
Location: http://www.google.com/
after
```

Raw Shell output

```
[user@localhost dir]# curl -m 5 -sI 216.58.219.206 | grep "Location:"
Location: http://www.google.com/
[user@localhost dir]#
```

Doesnt work either, I still see a new line.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of your Perl script, the output of `curl -m 5 -sI 216.58.219.206 | grep "Location:"` when run manually in the shell, and your expected output. Also, please make sure the code you've included works and reproduces your issue...as Avinash Raj pointed out in a now-deleted comment, your second snippet uses `$cmd` but there is no `$cmd` variable in the rest of the code.

Comment: Did you change `$\ ` or pass `-l` to `perl` (on the command line or the shebang line)?

Comment: Looking at the input helps -- perhaps there is more than one newline in your input, and you're just chomping one of them. Not enough information for us to help you.  I also highly recommend not using a regex for this -- that is the whole point of chomp(). If it's not working the way you think, then it's an issue with the input.

Comment: I have pasted the output for both the code snippets

Comment: I have also added raw shell output as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curl response is coming back with **\r\n** instead of just **\n**.

Use **od** (octal-dump) to see for yourself (**-c** means show characters):

```
curl -m 5 -sI 216.58.219.206 | grep Location: | od -c
0000000   L   o   c   a   t   i   o   n   :       h   t   t   p   :   /
0000020   /   w   w   w   .   g   o   o   g   l   e   .   c   o   m   /
0000040  \r  \n
0000042
```

You will need to remove both characters.

```
$location =~ s|\s*$||;  # Remove all trailing whitespace
```

Comment: Hi. Yup, I just discovered that a few minutes ago. Thank you so much anyways! Also, even if there are trailing whitespaces why isn't the regex removing "\n

Comment: Your regex does remove \n, but not \r.  \s matches all whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove tab, spaces, newline and carriage return using tr

```
curl -m 5 -sI 216.58.219.206 | grep Location: | tr -d '\011\012\040'
```